# resolving laravel 5.3 route name conflict

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this app in laravel 5.3 on my local machine that uses two `controllers`

> AdminUsersController and AgentUsersController

Now I set their `routes` in the following ways:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function(){


  Route::get('/admin', function(){
    return view('admin.index');
  });


  Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');

  Route::resource('admin/posts', 'AdminPostsController');
});


Route::group(['middleware' => 'agent'], function(){

  Route::get('/agent', function(){
    return view('agent.index');
  });

  Route::resource('agent/posts', 'AgentPostsController');

});
```

When I `list` the routes in this with `php artisan route:list` I get the following out come:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                     | Name          | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                       |               | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                   |               | Closure                                                                | web,admin    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/posts             | posts.index   | App\Http\Controllers\AdminPostsController@index                        | web,admin    |
|
|        | GET|HEAD  | agent/posts             | posts.index   | App\Http\Controllers\AgentPostsController@index                        | web,agent    |
|        | POST      | agent/posts             | posts.store   | App\Http\Controllers\AgentPostsController@store                        | web,agent    |
```

Notice that the `URI agent/posts` has the `name` `posts.index` and that the `URI admin/posts` has the `name`  `posts.index`.

Now in my `blade template` when I added the `route` for an `admin user` like so `{{route('posts.index')}}`. I get the `URI mydomain/agent/posts` instead of `mydomain/admin/posts`. How do I let `route` in `blade` know which of the `URIs` to pick.

I know I can also do `URL('/admin/posts')` to pick the right one, but I am wondering if using `route` method is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can **override** the names of one of your Resource controllers! Just pass another argument to the resource method, providing an array with the 'names' keyword as the index and another array as the value:

```
Route::resource('agent/posts', 'AgentPostsController', ['names' => [
    'index' => 'agent.posts.index'
]]);
```

Comment: why can't `laravel` resolve this based on my `role authentication` added to the app.

Comment: @udoyen There are ways to change the routing for different roles/user types, though this wasn't what you've asked.